# AngularJS: Create a custom Object which is able to use $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm currently converting my Javascript App from jQuery to AngularJS.
I used a lot of Object which modified the DOM and animate my elements. I wanted to create a factory, but I can't access to the scope, and that's not why they're made for.

A directive seems to be a good solution, but I don't want to declare a new element, or an attribute in my DOM, and I want to be able to use it as an object in my controller, and I want that object to access to the current controller scope.

For exemple:

```
myModule.controller("myController", ['$scope', 'Animation',
    function($scope, Animation) {
       Animation.doSomeStuff();
    }
]);
```

Is there any solution, or good way to do this ?

EDIT:
The ultra complet version of my jQuery object that I want to convert into the Angular way:

```
function Loader() {
var that = this;

this.STATES = new Array("sleep", "animate", "complete");

this.state;
this.animationDuration;
this.animation;
this.currentDiv;
this._completeTimer;
this._contenderResized = new Array();

//Events
this.onComplete = function(){};
this.onStop = function(){};
this.onStart = function(){};

this.init = function(animationName) {

    this.state = "sleep";
    this.animationDuration = 300;

    this.animation = animationName;

    switch(this.animation) {
        case "circle":
            this._initCircle();
            break;
        case "free":
            this._initSquare();
            break;
        case "square":
            this._initSquare();
            break;
    }

};

this.reset = function() {
    this.state = "sleep";
    this.currentDiv.find(".vote").removeClass("activated");

    that.currentDiv.find(".loader").hide();

    switch(this.animation) {
        case "circle":
            this._resetCircle();
            break;
        case "free":
            this._resetSquare();
            break;
        case "square":
            this._resetSquare();
            break;
    }



    this.onComplete = function() {};
    this.currentDiv = "";
};

this._removeAnimationClass = function() {
    this.currentDiv.find(".vote").removeClass("activated");

    var loaderCursor = this.currentDiv.find(".loader-cursor");

    if(loaderCursor.hasClass("loader-cursor-right"))
        loaderCursor.removeClass("loader-animate-right");

    if(loaderCursor.hasClass("loader-cursor-left"))
        loaderCursor.removeClass("loader-animate-left");

    loaderCursor.removeClass("loader-animate");
    loaderCursor.removeClass("loader-complete");
};

this.start = function(contenderDiv) {
    this.currentDiv = contenderDiv;
    this._animate(contenderDiv);
    this._completeTimer = setTimeout(this._complete, this.animationDuration);
};

this.stop = function() {
    if(this.state !== "animate" || !this.currentDiv) return;
    clearTimeout(this._completeTimer);
    switch(this.animation) {
        case "circle" :
            this._stopCircle();
            break;
        case "free":
            this._stopSquare();
            break;
        case "square":
            this._stopSquare();
            break;
    }


    setTimeout(function() {
        //that.currentDiv.find(".loader").hide();
    }, 20);
};

this._animate = function(contenderDiv) {
    this.state = "animate";
    switch (this.animation) {
        case "circle" :
            this._animateCircle(contenderDiv);
            break;
        case "free":
            this._animateSquare(contenderDiv);
            break;
        case "square":
            this._animateSquare(contenderDiv);
            break;
    }
};

this._complete = function() {
    that.state = "complete";
    switch (that.animation) {
        case "circle" :
            that._completeCircle();
            break;
        case "free":
            var loaderCursor = that.currentDiv.find(".loader-cursor");
            loaderCursor.addClass("loader-complete");
            break;
        case "square":
            var loaderCursor = that.currentDiv.find(".loader-cursor");
            loaderCursor.addClass("loader-complete");
            break;
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        that.onComplete();
        that.reset();
    }, 300);
};

this._resizeLoaderToContainImage = function(contenderDiv){

    if(jQuery.inArray(contenderDiv.find(".vote").attr("rel"),this._contenderResized) !== -1)
        return;

    var img = contenderDiv.find(".contenderImg");

    var imageSrc = jQuery(img).css('backgroundImage')
                   .replace(/url\((['"])?(.*?)\1\)/gi, '$2')
                    .split(',')[0];    
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSrc;
    var bgwidth = image.width,
    bgheight = image.height,    
    bgContainWidth = jQuery(img).width();

    var bgContainHeight = (bgheight*bgContainWidth)/bgwidth;


    var decimal = bgContainHeight.toString().split('.');

    if(decimal[0]>=5)
    {
       bgContainHeight = Math.ceil(bgContainHeight);
    }
    else
    {
       bgContainHeight = Math.floor(bgContainHeight);
    }

    var hRatio = bgheight / parseInt(contenderDiv.css("height"));

    var testWidth = bgwidth / hRatio;

    var decimal = bgContainHeight.toString().split('.');

    if(decimal[0]>=5)
    {
       testWidth = Math.ceil(testWidth);
    }
    else
    {
       testWidth = Math.floor(testWidth);
    }

    console.log("test "+testWidth);

    var loader = contenderDiv.find(".loader");

    loader.css("height", bgContainHeight);
    loader.css("width", testWidth);

    //Center Horizontal
    var marginTop = bgContainHeight / 2;
    loader.css("margin-top", -marginTop);

    //Center Vertical
    var marginLeft = testWidth / 2;
    loader.css("margin-left", -marginLeft);


    this._contenderResized.push(contenderDiv.find(".vote").attr("rel"));
};

/**********************
 *          SQUARE
 **********************/
this._initSquare = function() {

    /*jQuery('.contender').hover(function(){
        //IN
        jQuery(this).find(".loader").show();
        that._resizeLoaderToContainImage(jQuery(this));
    },
     function(){
        //OUT
        jQuery(this).find(".loader").hide();
    });*/
};

this._animateSquare = function(contenderDiv) {

    contenderDiv.find(".contenderImg").addClass("loader-animate");
    contenderDiv.find(".vkrz").stop(true, true).hide().fadeIn(300);

    if(contenderDiv.find("#contenderA").length === 1) {
        jQuery("#contenderB").find(".contenderImg").addClass("loader-animate-grayscale");
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#contenderA").find(".contenderImg").addClass("loader-animate-grayscale");
    }
};

this._stopSquare = function() {
    if(this.currentDiv.find("#contenderA").length === 1) {
        jQuery("#contenderB").find(".contenderImg").removeClass("loader-animate-grayscale");
    }
    else {
        jQuery("#contenderA").find(".contenderImg").removeClass("loader-animate-grayscale");
    }
    this.currentDiv.find(".vkrz").hide();
    this.currentDiv.find(".contenderImg").removeClass("loader-animate");
    this._removeAnimationClass();
};

this._resetSquare = function() {
    jQuery(".vkrz").hide();
    jQuery(".contenderImg").removeClass("loader-animate loader-animate-grayscale");
    this._removeAnimationClass();
};

/**********************
 *          CIRCLE
 **********************/

this._initCircle = function() {
    jQuery('.contender').hover(function(){
    //IN
    jQuery(this).find(".loader").stop(true, true).addClass("loader-hover");
},
 function(){
    //OUT 
    jQuery(this).find(".loader").stop(true, true).removeClass("loader-hover");
});
};

this._animateCircle = function(contenderDiv) {
    contenderDiv.find(".loader").stop(true, true).addClass("loader-animate");
};

this._stopCircle = function() {
    this.currentDiv.find(".vote").removeClass("activated");
    this.currentDiv.find('.loader').removeClass("loader-animate");

};

this._resetCircle = function() {
    this.currentDiv.find(".vote").removeClass("activated");
    jQuery(".loader").removeClass("loader-animate loader-complete").show();
};

this._completeCircle = function() {
    this.currentDiv.find(".loader").addClass('loader-complete');
};
}
```

Comment: Animation should be a factory or service.  Can you post that code along with a sample html template it is using.

Comment: I don't really have a code of the angular version for now, I just want to create an object which is able to access to the scope and modify the DOM.

Comment: Without seeing sample code, it is really hard to say.  Objects don't modify the dom in the way you do in jquery, so share a FULL example to determine if you really mean a directive, service, or controller.

Comment: I edited with the full code of my jquery object that I want to convert :)

Comment: there is not going to be a 1-to-1 conversion of your JQuery object and its representation in Angular. You would probably replicate it using several built-in directives, a few custom ones and a few custom services.

Comment: So that's a lot of code. I agree with @Rob's comment.  You will need to create some directives and custom services and converting that entire thing is probably too much for one question.

Comment: Ok, apparently there is no way to inject a custom "Object" which is using the scope with angularjs. I'll try to reorganize all my code to make it work. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `factory` is appropriate here. It seems very well suited for the job:

```
myModule.factory('Animator', function() {
    // return new Animator instance
    // or if you want a singleton just return it without 'new'
    return new Loader();
});
```

Then, your `controller` can use it like so:

```
myModule.controller("myController", function($scope, Animator) {
    // init circle animation
    Animator.init('circle');

    $scope.actionOne = function() {
        Animator.start(...);
    };

    $scope.actionTwo = function() {
        Animator.stop();
        Animator.reset();
    };
    ...
});
```

So, in this case, you're not passing `$scope` to `service` or `factory` instance. Instead, you inject such instance into `controller` so you can make use of it together with `$scope` variables. It can also be injected in as many controllers as you want, too, so it's highly reusable.

Comment: @Najie Glad it helps. Though it's true that you would need to rewrite a whole lot if you want to go with pure Angular solution, finding the right balance between Angular and Jquery during the transitioning period is the key here, IMO. Anyway, good luck! :)

Comment: Yeah, I try to not use jQuery at all, but it mean a lot of rewriting/refactoring. It's a good exercice for practicing AngularJS :p

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inject directives into your controller. So you can either create a directive and add it to your HTML or create a service, inject it into your controller and pass $scope into it.

It's usually a bad practice to pass $scope into a service though so I would probably go with a directive.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to use a service. Can I create an object using a directive ?

Comment: @rob, it is really hard to answer this question considering it isn't very specific yet.  Najie may want a directive, maybe just a service really dependsd on what is meant by "modify the DOM" as that's what simple model changes do on the scope.

Comment: Najie: no you cannot inject a directive into your controller (create an object). But as @lucuma said, how you want to deal with this may depend on what you are trying to do with the DOM.